# @font-face not displaying correctly for particular font

Tags: html, css, font-face

We are trying to display text with different fonts in same html files without installing it in device.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="../../fonts/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body >
<div>
  <div class="e_content ">
    <div class="e_number">1.</div>
   <div class="e_text"> <a href="../../chapters/english/v/v1/v1_1.html"> Bh¤µ¤Ô¤Â×Ô¤ßuÈ¤ÌÚÙ ¤´a¢¿¤ÔßuÂÂÛ ÏÚ´¤ÔÚ ÔÛÖá. </a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="e_content1">
    <div class="e_number1">2.</div>
    <div class="e_text1"> <a href="../../chapters/english/v/v1/v1_2.html">  »ÜU¢ïùãæ Ï¢ãéS²¢æ Ðí…¢²ï² </a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In example first div is using Trans.ttf and second div is using AnamikaTwo.ttf which is defined in StyleSheet.css. But while viewing second div is viewed proper and first is not getting displayed properly.

In Stylesheet.css defined font-face as:

```
@font-face
    {
        font-family: "AnamikaTwo";
        src: url('AnamikaTwo.ttf'); format("truetype");
    }
@font-face
    {
        font-family: "Trans";
        src: url('Trans.ttf'); format("truetype");
    }
.e_number { float:left; background:url(index-number-bg.png) no-repeat left top; width:45px; height:50px; line-height:30px; text-align:center; color:#6a2525; font-family:"Trans"; margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;}
.e_content {float:left; width:100%; margin:1px 0px 0px 0px; padding:8px 0; background:#fdeec5;text-align:left;border-bottom: 1px solid #E4D4AA; opacity:0.6;}   
.e_text a {color:#6a2525; text-decoration:none; font-family:'Trans';}
.e_number1 { float:left; background:url(index-number-bg.png) no-repeat left top; width:45px; height:50px; line-height:30px; text-align:center; color:#6a2525; font-family:"AnamikaTwo"; margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;}
.e_content1 {float:left; width:100%; margin:1px 0px 0px 0px; padding:8px 0; background:#fdeec5;text-align:left;border-bottom: 1px solid #E4D4AA; opacity:0.6;}  
.e_text1 a {color:#6a2525; text-decoration:none; font-family:'AnamikaTwo';}
```

Download fonts from the link for reference: [click here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=fb9879c760ecd742&id=FB9879C760ECD742!112)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your fonts are legally embeddable for web-embedding, you can go here http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and then upload your font .tff's

Select 'optimal' or you can also access the 'expert' settings for specific embedding options which is particular useful if you only need some of the type variations and want to save on load time.

Once it's done processing all of the glyphs, you can click the 'download your kit' button and then open the zip archive containing a useable example of how to now embed your fonts using @font-face

If you open up the stylesheet.css, you'll see something like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'yourfont';
src: url('yourfont-webfont.eot');
src: url('yourfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('yourfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('yourfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('yourfont-webfont.svg#yourfont') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Keep in mind that if you upload your fonts to a /fonts directory, you'll then need to reference the files properly in your css file. (for example, ../font/yourfont-webfont.eot, etc.)

Hope this helps.

Adobe TypeKit is a great option too: https://typekit.com/ and saves the hassle of this custom embedding.